# Pass a template-defined local variable to parent component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass a local input from an input field from a child component to a parent component. Here is an example:

```
// Parent component export:
itemInput: string;

// Parent component template
<div>
  <add-item [itemInput]="itemInput"></add-item>
</div>
<div [hidden]="itemInput.length <= 0">
  <ul>
    <li *ngIf="checkEntry(itemInput) == true">
      Some data here
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

// Child Component template
<input type="text" (keyup)="0" #itemInput [(ngModel)]="itemInput.value">
```

I'm still fairly unfamiliar with 2-way binding, but can't seem to figure it out. I understand the concept, but am still grasping the syntax for it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Also, if other information is needed, please let me know. Thanks

Edit:

Here's my error message:

EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in [itemInput.length <= 0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this make sure you define output for the child one, this will set up an event channel through which child can push updates to the parent.

Child component:

```
@Output() itemInput = new EventEmitter()
```

and a template will look something like

```html
<input type="text" (keyup)="0" #input [(ngModel)]="input.value" (ngModelChange)="itemInput.emit(input)">
```

Then in parent component template becomes:

```html
template: `
  <div>
    <add-item (itemInput)="itemInput = $event.value"></add-item>
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="itemInput?.length <= 0"> <!-- or [hidden]="!itemInput || itemInput.length <= 0" -->      
    <ul>
      <li *ngIf="checkEntry(itemInput) == true">
        Some data here
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
`
```

Note `?` in the expression `[hidden]="itemInput?.length <= 0"` it prevents the error you see when no data is yet entered. Or you can also write `[hidden]="!itemInput || itemInput.length <= 0"`.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Xvu4M9H6iVqGHme4lgxW?p=preview

Comment: Great! thank you, this worked :)  Thank you for explaining the `?` expression as well. I've still got lots to learn but enjoying it thus far

Comment: What is the use of `@Input` in this example? I don't think its existence makes any diff.

Comment: @micronyks Thanks for noticing it, of course it's not needed in this case. Input on parent declares what properties parent component defines so that parent component could also receive input from its own parent. But in this case parent doesn't need it. Instead only child needs to declare event channel with Output.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `@Output() someFieldChange;` in the child component.

Notify about changes by calling `emit()`

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="0"  [(ngModel)]="itemInput.value" (ngModelChange)="someFieldChange.emit($event)">
```

Then you can bind to it in parent

```
<child-comp (someFieldChange)="doSomething()"></child-comp>
```